# I have a string in the following format. How can I find the content of the indexes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string in the following format. How can I find the content of the indexes?

```
string_example = "matrix[1][2]"
```

`content = 1 , 2`

thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Using `re.findall` and `\d+`

```
string_example = "matrix[1][2]"
import re
x=re.findall(r'\d+',string_example)
print(x)
```

Returns:

```
['1', '2']
```

See demo for [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/A55W4o/1)

Alternatively:

```
x=re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]',string_example)
```

Check demo for [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/L9UW91/1)

---

For extracting indices with brackets:

```
x=re.findall(r'\[\d+\]',string_example)
```

Demo: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/piuzqK/1)

Comment: @amir.h most welcome. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import re
re.findall('\[(.*?)\]','matrix[1][2]')
```

Comment: This can be found with [find](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm), no? Why start a regex engine just for this? (I noticed your edit, and I do not agree that this is a regex only Question)

Comment: @Scratte, Why don't you send solution with find, I want learn from you :)))

Comment: I'm not even a python developer. I know regex though and I know when not to use it too :)

Comment: @amir.h, welcome bro, you can `accept` or `upvote` my answer

Answer (score 0):

If the string **always** end in:
`[x][y]`

You could just do:

```py
y = int(string_example[-2])
x = int(string_example[-5])
```

But if `x` or `y` can be bigger then 9, then you should use regex like so:

```py
import re
x = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]',string_example)
print(x)
```

The output will be:

```py
['1', '2']
```

*Note that the output will be a list of **strings** and not integers.